# I have upgrade Magento 2.2.7 to 2.3.2 complete but the Front-end not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-upgrade

upgrade Magento 2.2.7 to 2.3.2 complete but frontend not working Swissup/argento-essence/ theme error at the below-attached screenshot.
https://prnt.sc/okp009

Comment: do you understand this error?

Comment: Are you run this command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL -f ?